# How can I make flex items appropriately spaced in my nav?

Tags: html, css

At the moment, I'm working on a test page and was trying to adjust the free space between the different nav bar sections. The flex: x x xx function doesn't change anything, doesn't matter which variables I use. I'm a complete beginner when it comes to HTML/CSS so maybe the answer is quite easy though. Thankful for every kind of help!

```css
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 40rem;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <h1 id="#logo">TestPage</h1>
    <li><a href="#locations">Locations</a></li>
    <li><a href="#benefits">Benefits</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and update your question with a [mre] of your code - all relevant parts (we need the HTML too!) - so we can better assist you! :)

Comment: Thanks! Just updated the code and provided the HTML part as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have `nav ul` in CSS but no `nav` in HTML

Comment: Had `nav` in my code, just forgot to post it with the other parts.

Comment: What are you looking to achieve? `justify-content: space-around;` is spacing everything for you and the flex property is more for individual items in a flexbox, not the box itself. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Comment: I want to have the logo, then a big space and then the nav bar sections, but with a smaller space between those sections than between the logo and the sections. It should exactly be like in that link you commented. Only thing is that literally nothing changes when I use the flex property with x x xx rem.

Comment: please update your code i can't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `nav` a flex container, then separate the logo from the nav items which we'll also use flex on so we can align them and size them responsively inside the nav container. Make sure you set a width and height value on the primary container nav as well (in this case I used 100vw so it spans the entire length of the viewport)

Make the logo (the  in this case) space itself away from the nav items using the flex property (I just picked 10rem, you can use whatever you like)

You can then space your nav items using flex as well. You'll have to consider a media query or wrapping the nav as the screen size starts to chart into mobile territory but this at least gets you going.

Here's a terrific breakdown on how flexboxes work: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Let me know if that helps and if you need any clarification on anything.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 1rem;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style: none;
}

h1 {
  padding-left: 2rem;
  flex: 1 1 10rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h1 id="#logo">TestPage</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#locations">Locations</a></li>
    <li><a href="#benefits">Benefits</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```